# Why Object Class definition makes difference

Tags: python, class, oop, object, instance

How to make sure that three Item's instances are all unique "self-contained" variables and not just the same data with three different names?

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID=None
        self.name=None

items=[]
for row in range(3):
    item=Item
    item.ID=row
    item.name='Item %s'%row
    items.append(item)

for item in items:
    print item.name

print 'True?:', items[0]==items[1]==items[2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the line -

```
item=Item
```

This sets the class to `item` , it does not create a new instance of that class. You need to call `Item` as `Item()` , to create a new instance of the class -

```
item=Item()
```

---

In your original case, since you were putting the same class to `item` variable, and creating/changing its class variables - `ID` and `name` , and then inserting that particular class to the `items` list.

In every iteration of the loop, `item` was pointing to the same class (not instance, but class) , since you were not creating instances of the class, instead you were directly getting the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have an `__init__` method, you might as well take advantage of its features.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

items = []

for row in range(3):
    item = Item(id=row, name='Item {}'.format(row))
    items.append(item)

for item in items:
    print item.name
```

For completeness, as mentioned above your original code is creating new names that points to the class `Item`. Calling `Item()` will return a new instance every time that can be assigned to a variable.